# Looking for a font with leaning A (image attached)

Tags: fonts

tried the site [what the font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) with no luck.  I am looking for a font (Free since for one time use in a title) that has this leaning "A".  I know the font is a popular one as I've seen it in many designs as of late.

[image]

Here is an example of a similar font found in an image online.  If anyone has any ideas what font this or one similar please let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it matter which side the 'A' tilts to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font is a redrawn Avant Garde (J U and E are different). Avant Garde was originally designed with alternative forms such as the straight-sided A you illustrate — and another leaning the other way, along with lots of other combining forms. That particular A would have been used in a word like NATURAL, so it butted up against the N and slid under the T.

[Example at MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/avant+garde/fonts/) — use JOURNEY as the sample text. The R is the clincher.

Edit: there are examples of the alternative combining forms at [FontShop](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/family/itc_avant_garde_gothic_ef/). But I *very* much doubt that there is anything free.

Comment: That's it! Thank you.  I have Avant Garde, but not the alternatives.  Will probably mock something up in illustrator since this is only for the title in a video presentation.  Thanks again for your answer.